# How to type on combo box using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I am finding difficulties when try to type on combo box using selenium. Actually the combo box using javascript and ajax to load the data. when the user click button **dropdown**, then the combo box load the data. actually I am finding difficulties since I can't use function `selectByValue()` or `selectByVisibleText()`. here is the code :

```
<table id="isc_U5" class="OBFormFieldSelectControl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="cursor:default;WIDTH:307px;" $9a="$9f" $89="isc_OBFKComboItem_8" role="presentation">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="white-space:nowrap;">
<input id="isc_U3" class="OBFormFieldSelectInputRequired" type="TEXT" tabindex="4078" style="WIDTH:281px;HEIGHT:17px;-moz-user-focus:normal;" autocomplete="OFF" onselect="isc_OBFKComboItem_8.$1162()" oninput="isc_OBFKComboItem_8._handleInput()" spellcheck="true" $9a="$9b" $89="isc_OBFKComboItem_8" handlenativeevents="false" name="transactionDocument"/>
</td>
<td id="isc_U7" class="OBFormFieldSelectPickerIcon" style="font-size:21px;">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. I have used JAVA

1. Use ordinary SendKeys :

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.OBFormFieldSelectInputRequired").sendKeys("Beginning letters of the word you want");
   ```
2. use `findElements` :

   ```
   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("list items cssSelector"));
           for (WebElement element : elements) {
               if (element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Enter the text you want")) {
                   element.click();
                    break;
               }
            }
   ```
3. or use `Java Robot` :

   ```
   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("list items cssSelector"));
   Robot bot = new Robot();
   bot.setAutoDelay(1);

   for (WebElement element : elements) {
            bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            if (element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Enter the text you want")) {
                bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                break;
            }
   }
   ```

Comment: I already use option number one and two but it is does not working. maybe option number 3 is the best answer right now. I will try to use it thank you @selva

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below c# Code.

```
IWebElement comboBoxElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("OBFormFieldSelectInputRequired"));
```

**Option1**
Directly send the ComboBox values by using SendKeys as it is a input element only.

```
comboBoxElement.SendKeys("ComboBox value to select");
```

**Option2**
Type Firts few characters of the value you are looking to select

```
comboBoxElement.SendKeys("TE");
```

This will let your application to display the UL and LI tags with li values starting with TE.. Now locate UL element and find its child LI elements. Iterate through each LI element and perform .click when desired value is found during iteration.

Comment: I already using sendKeys function but it does not working. I used java code maybe to change it to C# it will takes a lot of effort